# Avg para null con left join

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo dos tablas (respuestas y punt_respuestas) relacionadas por id_respuesta. Hay respuestas que no tienen puntuacion. Necesito sacar todas las respuestas con su media de puntuaciones. Uso esta consulta:

```
SELECT `respuestas`.`id_respuesta`, `respuestas`.`texto`, `respuestas`.`fecha`, `respuestas`.`nombre`, AVG(`punt_respuestas`.`puntuacion`) FROM `respuestas` LEFT JOIN `punt_respuestas` ON `respuestas`.`id_respuesta` = `punt_respuestas`.`id_respuesta`
```

Pero esto solo me devuelve las respuestas que tienen puntuación. Necesito que las que no la tienen, lo tome como 0.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función ifnull:

```
SELECT `respuestas`.`id_respuesta`, `respuestas`.`texto`, 
       `respuestas`.`fecha`, `respuestas`.`nombre`, 
        AVG(ifnull(`punt_respuestas`.`puntuacion`,0)) 
FROM `respuestas` 
LEFT JOIN `punt_respuestas` 
  ON `respuestas`.`id_respuesta` = `punt_respuestas`.`id_respuesta`
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo solucioné con group by. Si ponía ifnull no me los mostraba tampoco.

Comment: Gracias a ti por retroalimentarme, qué bueno que pudiste solucionar